# Days, Months and Years on two axis in R

Tags: r, date

I have a problem with this date format of my dataframe:
My df looks like this:

```
Year Month  1  2  3  4 ...  31
2010 1     10 22 34 48 ... 323  
2010 2     ...     ...
2010 3     ...     ...
2010 4     ...     ...
```

I would like to have a "classical" date format in the first column, something like this:

```
Date          Value
2010-01-01     10
2010-01-02     22
2010-01-03     34
2010-01-04     48
.
.
.
```

Could somebody help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to reshape into 'long' format with `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` and then `unite` the columns 'Year', 'Month', 'Day' to a single column and convert the `class` of the column to `Date` with `as.Date`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(Year, Month), names_to = 'Day', values_to = 'Value') %>%
   unite(Date, Year, Month, Day, sep="-") %>%
   mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
# A tibble: 12 x 2
#   Date       Value
#   <date>     <int>
# 1 2010-01-01    10
# 2 2010-01-02    22
# 3 2010-01-03    34
# 4 2010-01-04    48
# 5 2010-02-01     4
# 6 2010-02-02    12
# 7 2010-02-03    34
# 8 2010-02-04    44
# 9 2010-03-01    15
#10 2010-03-02    24
#11 2010-03-03    35
#12 2010-03-04    46
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L), Month = 1:3, `1` = c(10L, 
4L, 15L), `2` = c(22L, 12L, 24L), `3` = c(34L, 34L, 35L), `4` = c(48L, 
44L, 46L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```